I'm trying to make a login system in C language that hides the password with '*' while inputting, and loops back when the user enters the wrong info
However there are two problems with my code:

Backspace counts as an input.
When it loops back after the first failed attempt, it shows "Invalid username or password!" even though the login details are correct.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


...

do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\nEnter username: ");
        gets(username);
        printf("\nEnter password: ");
    
        do{
            password[i] = getch();
            if(password[i] != '\r')
            printf("*");
            i++;
        }while(password[i-1] != '\r');
        password[i-1] = '\0';
        
        if (strcmp(username, "dlsuuser1") == 0 & strcmp(password, "dlsuuser") == 0)
            indicator = 0;

        else if(strcmp(username, "dlsuuser2") == 0 && strcmp(password, "dlsuusers") == 0)
            indicator = 0;
        
        else{
            printf("\nInvalid username or password!");
            memset(password, '\0', sizeof(password));
            memset(username, '\0', sizeof(username));
            getch();
            i=0;
            indicator = 1;
            }
    }while(indicator != 0);

    printf("\nLogged in successfully!");

I tried to follow sources online but I can't seem to get it. I'm fairly new to C too. Also I have a theory about the second problem; where the program continues to do the array for the username and password (eg it appends on itself like how strcat works). Thank you to those who will answer!
Also if someone can show me to shorten and make the code more efficient, I would greatly appreciate it!
(Note: This is an activity where we're only allowed to do Basic I/O, Ladderized if -else, switch statements, functions except functions pass-by-reference,  any looping statements, arrays, and strings. In this case, the options might be limited. I apologize.)
I tried memset, strcpy (password, ""), and password[0]=\0 but nothing works.


don't getch() directly into the password array. Store the input in a temporary variable, check that temporary variable for '\r' and backspace (and other problematic inputs) before deciding how to carry on


Aside: gets() is obsolete and is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?

Don't reset i after you use it. Do it just before. Ditto with indicator.

Also, your first strcmp() call uses a bitwise AND (&) instead of a logical AND (&&). No compiler warnings?

Post a program not a snippet.

You should tag this windows as you use windows specific headers and external commands.
